# Flow3 / Zend Framework - Content for different pages

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, web, typo3-flow

I think the answer to my question is independent from the framework because the View functionality is rather similar between those two. But what I am using is Flow3.

I have a layout with the standard elements like the header, footer, navi, etc. Then I have the content placeholder. Now my website shall have a few static pages like 'Home', 'About Us', 'Imprint', etc. with no need for PHP code or special objects.
So what is the normal way to accomplish this? Does one create a Content-Controller and a new action+view for every page on the website? Or is there a method to have different content for different pages with just one action?

Answer (score -1):

That is not a serious question, is it?

In case it is, you will need to have two models. One for pages and one for content. Each page may have multiple content objects.

Comment: This is a serious question....
I don't get it how to build the static webpages with its content around the other models/controllers.

Comment: I do not know what you want to archive, but there is a raw viewhelper. So you can just add a few html snippets and output them using a raw viewhelper.

Comment: In case you really need a cms, you have to wait for TYPO3 Phoenix.